# export image from GCE

Tags: google-compute-engine

I would like to export a VM (Windows) image from my google compute engine account.
I found the relevant section explaining [how to import](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/creating-custom-image#importing_an_image) an image TO CGE, but I failed to find the information about how to export an image from CGE.
Do you nkow how it can be done and to which formats?

thanks,
R.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to export an instance's disk is by adding additional disk to your instance and create an image of that disk followed by copying that image to Google Cloud Storage bucket (so you can download it or share with others).

Steps:

- Add one more disk of the same size as your boot disk (or a bit larger) using [DevConsole](http://cloud.google.com/console)
- Format and mount the new disk

  `sudo mkdir /mnt/tmp`

  `sudo mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/disk/by-id/google-temporary-disk`

  `sudo mount -o discard,defaults /dev/disk/by-id/google-temporary-disk /mnt/tmp`
- Create the image

  `$ sudo dd if=/dev/disk/by-id/google-image-disk of=/mnt/tmp/disk.raw bs=4096`
- Then tar and gzip this file:

  `sudo tar czvf myimage.tar.gz disk.raw`
- Finally, upload your image to a bucket:

  `gsutil cp /mnt/tmp/myimage.tar.gz gs://BUCKET_NAME`

Comment: I would like to refine my question. I already have an image that I'm using to create instances.What will be the steps that I need to do on that image.? note that I tried to tar.gz it with no luck. I'm probably doing something wrong. Is it possible to do it on existing image?

Comment: @Burgaz In this case, you'll need to create an instance using your image and then using this instance to complete the steps in my answer.

Comment: There is no /dev/disk/ in console, isn't it?

    ~$ cd /dev/disk/
    No such file or directory